# How to use ctfconvert and ctfmerge in cmake

Tags: cmake, solaris-10

I want to use the ctfconvert and ctfmerge in CMake. I went through couple of links below.

https://java.net/projects/solaris/sources/on-src/content/usr/src/tools/scripts/nightly.sh

http://lethargy.org/~jesus/writes/mdb-ctf-dwarf-and-other-angelic-things/#.V-JUFPl97X4

The source in links states that we need to create object file of the source and then apply ctfmerge and ctfconvert over that. I came to know that there is a facility to create OBJECT library in CMake. But I am not getting how to apply these ctfconvert and ctfmerge on OBJECT libraries as $<"TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib> can only be used in add_library() or add_executable().

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to install onbld package on Solaris 11 or need to build Solaris 10 source code to get onbld package to install ctf binaries.
Then ultimately need to call ctf binaries in CMakeList.txt to run. We need to create a object file from ctfconvert binary and then need to use ctfmerge when we create an executable/shared library to merge the obhect file containing ctf header information to newly created executable/shared library. 
If we need to create static library, we just need to use ctfconvert over the file to create the object file containing ctf header which will put those files in archive. When we use this static library in creation of executable/shared library, at that time, we need to use ctfmerge over each object file from static library.